# PureComponent keeps rendering even though no state/prop changes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-component

I'm trying to learn and test React.PureComponent and it keeps rendering even though no state changes for that pure component.

My PureComponent is very simple and it accepts only one Redux Action function via `connect` hoc

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Container,
    Button
} from 'reactstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { resetWorkouts } from '../actions/workoutApiActions'

class About extends React.PureComponent {
    render () {
        const { resetWorkouts } = this.props;
        console.log('in about render...')
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Container>
                    <h2>Api Data Reset</h2>
                    <Button color="danger" onClick={resetWorkouts}>Reset Data</Button>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        resetWorkouts: () => dispatch(resetWorkouts())
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(About);
```

In the above code, you can see that, there is no state in the component.  It only accepts the action function as `props` from `connect`.  However, whenever I clicks on the `Reset Data` button, it keeps calling the `render` method as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

In the screenshot, I can see that, global state store has been changed whenever, I click a button.  But, that state is not used in my PureComponent and it should be out of the scope and my component should ignore to re-render.

Or Redux Action functions are created every time the global state store has been changed.  And **passed as a new object** to my PureComponent ?

Theoretically, I don't need to write my own `shouldComponentUpdate` function, right?  I'm confused and could you please help me to understand about this behaviour?

My goal is I don't want my PureComponent to render again when a user clicks a button.

**Updates:**

I have tried like the following according to this [article](https://daveceddia.com/redux-mapdispatchtoprops-object-form/) and it's still re-rendering

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    resetWorkouts
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this because react do a shallow comparison between the prevProps and the nextProps,
and you can control that only in the `shouldComponentUpdate`, react doesn't know that the dispatcher is the same one from the previous render, because you are using return inside the `mapDispatchToProps` function.
In your component and in your case, while the function will remain the same, you can go with two paths:

**path 1:**

override the `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle hook, to be as the following:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(){
return false;
}
```

**path 2:**

get rid of the return inside `mapDispatchToProps` and simplify the connect  so it be as the following:

```
`conncect(state => ({}), {
        resetWorkouts: resetWorkouts})(YourComponent);`
```

using one of the above paths should make you good to go

Comment: In Path2, I am not able to compile without `return` inside the mapDispatchToProps.  It shows an error -> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  I couldn't find any usage without `return` in Redux connect

Comment: I've updated my comment, sorry im not used to use `mapDispatchToProps`, i hope the update solve your problem

Comment: It's very strange that... if my `AboutPage` is in `React-Router <Route>`, it keeps re-rendering again and again.  If I commented out that line in my routes and use `AboutPage` as the `component` in another component, it renders only once.

Comment: I can't tell you without seeing the code, but I think you are not using `<Switch>`, the switch component will render only the first matching route, without it, the all routed components will be re-rendered each time the route change, I hope that answered your question.

Comment: I managed to replicate this behaviour on CodeSandbox.  It's here https://codesandbox.io/s/ww2lm5197w .  If you go to /ShowCounter, it doesn't re-render.  But if you browse /about, it keeps triggering the `Render()` method

Comment: yes I see, the problem here is `PureComponents` make a shallow comparison between the `previous props` and the `next props`, and that is not a problem with your `About` component only, its the same with your `showConter` as well, if you logged the props of one of your components, you can see like history props that came from `Route` component, which contains a complex data that not passing in the shallow comparison, so react will update the component more and more.

Comment: the prev. comment was to show you the problem, now the answer of your question is, that react doesn't render the whole `JSX` in the render function, each render, react take a snapshot, of how the `JSX` tree looks like before applying the changes to the dom, the snapshot is a detailed one, unlike the shallow comparison, so when react came again to re-render the `ShowCounter` component, it noticed that the `About` component still at the same place, and has the same tree, so it will not re-render it, that's what virtual dom came with as a benefit, hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detail explanation.  It is crystal clear now.  Happy Easter :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your component is rendering is because everytime the following function executes:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        resetWorkouts: () => dispatch(resetWorkouts())
    }
}
```

your components receives a new instance of a property named `resetWorkouts`(because you're creating an inline array function). You may look at the `ownProps` to check if your component already have the `resetWorkouts`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        resetWorkouts: ownProps.resetWorkouts || () => dispatch(resetWorkouts())
    }
}
```